# What is more secure way to store javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xaml

For ex.: I need to prevent replacement of js. What is more secure way to store it? In page xaml or in separate .js file?
I think that .js file could be replaced in browser cache. But js in page code more difficult to replace.

Comment: There is no secure way to store javascript in a browser, as javascript is not meant to be secure, it's accessible to the user.

Comment: The best you can do is [obfuscate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) your JS, this makes it difficult to read or interpret. However, it by no means makes it "secure" because there are tools out there that can reverse the procedure. Fact is, your fighting a losing battle, accepting the fact you *can't* secure it is the first step towards the correct solution.

Comment: James, so this is something like JS minifying?

Comment: @AsTi partially, however, minifying is not the same as obfuscating (although, they generally come hand in hand). Obfuscation is the process of renaming variables, method names etc. to reduce the chances of someone making any sort of sense of what's actually going on. If they can't make sense of the script then it would make it very difficult for them to "replace" it in a malicious way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unwinnable fight - mostly because there are browser plugins like Greasemonkey which are created exactly for the purpose of changing scripts that are executed on the page.

Since JavaScript runs on the client, there is nothing you can do to prevent the chance of the user modifying it, skipping some functions etc. Always revalidate the data and any calculations on the server.

Comment: So, there is now way to prevent user credentials theft which're processed in js?

Comment: @AsTi - do not store any kind of credentials in JS (ever). If you need to authenticate AJAX requests, either store an authentication ticket in cookie (if it is on the same domain) or use some sort of federated authentication.

Comment: Absolutely, I don't do this. But what in case if I need to check what user enters through JS and someone replace this JS and sniff user inputs?

Comment: @AsTi - how is that (network sniffer, keylogger etc.) related to JavaScript files being replaced?

Comment: For ex.: if someone add a function into JS which is saving user inputs and sending them using POST to an attacker?

Comment: You cannot prevent that from happening if the attacker has control of the user's computer. To prevent it from happening from remote attackers, read about XSS and CSRF (cross site scripting and cross site request forgery).